# How To Clear vim RO Flag

Tags: vim

My test.pl was under control of the Perl debugger. I forgot that, and tried to modify the file, but vim told me the file was protected against writes and showed an RO in the status line. (I'm using gVim.)

I closed the debugger, and checked the protections on test.pl

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ics ics 494 Jul  3 15:25 test.pl`

Even when I performed an e! on test.pl (using ftp:// syntax); closed test.pl and re-opened the file, it was still showing RO. I had to close vim; restart it; and upon loading test.pl again, its protections were correct.

How can I clear the RO flag without exiting vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type

```
:se noro
```

which is short for:

```
:set noreadonly
```

(followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, of course).

That will tell vim that you're not editing the file in read-only mode, but it won't override any system-level protections if you don't have permission to write to it. (There might be resaons other than the directory permission bits that you wouldn't be able to write to a file; for example, the file might be locked or on a read-only file system.)